# select a element in iframe with jQuery

Tags: jquery

For example:

```
<html><body><object data="" id="something"></object></body></html>
```

How can i select a tag in this object?
Tks ^^

Comment: In title you talk about `iframe` in the question about the `object`. Do you mean selecting an element in the `iframe` from its parent (the html page containing the iframe) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the iframe contents first to apply selector on it. You can use jQuery [contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) function to get.

```
var objSomething = $('#iframeID').contents().find('#something');
```

You should call this script when iframe is loaded. You can use `window.load` to ensure that.

```
$(window).load(function(){
   var objSomething = $('#iframeID').contents().find('#something');
   alert(objSomething[0].id);
});
```